# Intellij IDEA server configuration permission issue with Wildfly 8.1

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, jboss7.x, wildfly-8

I am running Intellij 13 on Ubuntu, Wildfly 8.1 resides locally.

Wildfly startup script requires sudo/root permissions. Intellij is installed and runs under my username, and IntelliJ is not able to start the application sever and deploy my war file, and the errors all point to a permission problem:

.
.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014922: Directory /opt/wildfly-8/standalone/data/content is not writable
.
.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wildfly-8/standalone/log/server.log (Permission denied)

I tried setting username and password in the Run | Edit Configurations form but it appears that is for something else.

Since I login to Intellij with my local username, it cannot start the application server without additional information to start the script, but I'm not able to locate where that information should go.

The owner of the files and directories under /opt/wildfly-8 are wildfly.wildfly

Wildfly starts up cleanly via "sudo /etc/init.d/wildfly-8 start"

Comment: Although running chmod 777 might work, this seems a hack... there must be a normal way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

I did: `sudo chown --recursive my_username:my_username` on the whole wildfly directory and it starts now.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Intellij Ultimate 2018.2 on Ubuntu. I created a group in Ubuntu named `wildfly` and changed the group of the WildFly installation folder to my new WildFly group. Then I assigned `rwx` permissions to the group and added my login user to the wildfly group. So now I don't get the 'permission denied' error when IDEA starts WildFly for the first time and WildFly tries to create a `server.log` file.